# Flask: proper way of using routes and functions

Tags: python, flask

I wrote a small flask server.
However, one of the routes was getting large so i thought of creating an external .py file, that contains all the logic in a function, and when the route gets executed, it simply calls that function in that different python file.

However, i also had to get parameters from a form.
So my new route was:

```
@app.route('/convert', methods=['POST'])
conversion_item = request.form.get('item')
conversion_method = request.form.get('method')
#HERE CALL THE FUNCTION
convertMy(conversion_item, conversion_method)
return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

However, when i execute this, i get:

```
  File "server.py", line 24
    conversion_item = request.form.get('item')
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Do i have to put everything in that route inside a function?
Then i will have a function under that route, that will call another function? That seems weird to me.

How can i "glue" this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `@` in `@app.route` represents a function decorator, it has to decorate a function. It is perfectly normal for a function to call another function.

```
@app.route('/convert', methods=['POST'])
def convert():
    conversion_item = request.form.get('item')
    conversion_method = request.form.get('method')
    #HERE CALL THE FUNCTION
    convertMy(conversion_item, conversion_method)
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, you can import a function from another file and call it within a view function.

The error message you provide, though, has nothing to do with an import.

In Python you need to indent code blocks.

You have written a function like this...

```
def function():
return "something"
```

but you need to indent the function body like this...

```
def function():
    return "something"
```

So it would look like this...

```
from somewhere import large_function


def function():
    large_funtion()
    return "something"
```